# substring, replacing format

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, qsqlquery

hello i have row of data 1000 records, that i need to replace and substring in the format like below:

i have this format 004320487091 and i need to convert it to 0.432.487.091 any thought any helps please?

Comment: You need this for MySQL, SQL Server and QSqlQuery???

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the poster does not appear to have attempted any solution on his own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is always going to be same format as mentioned in your question then try this.
Use `STUFF Function` to get the result.

```
select stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff('004320487091',3,0,'.'),7,1,'.'),11,0,'.'),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use concat plus substring like that

```
SELECT concat(substring('004320487091',2,1)
,'.',
(substring('004320487091',3,3))
,'.',
(substring('004320487091',7,3))
,'.',
(substring('004320487091',10,3)))
```

Comment: its says no concat function below error msg Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name. @Dudi Konfino

Comment: i am using sql server 2012 and it works perfect

Comment: am using 2008r2, might this new function not in sql2008 @Dudi Konfino